Cinta de opciones (Ribbon) en Excel usando c# y ExcelDNA
He intentado crear un complemento de Excel usando c# y ExcelDNA que contenga una cinta de opciones. Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo en Excel nunca muestra la cinta de opciones. He revisado el archivo DNA y todo y está perfecto.
Este es el código del Addin en C#:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using ExcelDna.Integration;
using ExcelDna.Integration.CustomUI; 

[ComVisible(true)] 
public class MyAddIn : ExcelRibbon { 
public override string GetCustomUI(string RibbonID) 
{ return File.ReadAllText("CustomUI.xml"); } 

public void RunMyMacro(IRibbonControl control) {  XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcAlert, "¡Botón de la cinta clicado!"); }

y este el del Ribbon.xml:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
 <ribbon>
  <tabs> 
   <tab id="MyCustomTab" label="Mi Pestaña"> <group id="MyGroup" label="Mi 
    Grupo"> 
   <button id="MyButton" label="Mi Botón" onAction="RunMyMacro" /> </group>
   </tab> 
  </tabs> 
 </ribbon> 
</customUI>

¿Que debo hacer o qué no estoy haciendo?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
